# not able to form URL by passing parameter for REST API

Tags: python

I am trying to call REST API and passing required values as parameter.

First, I tried passing values directly and got the URL value as expected.
I have mock all values to hide original credentials but the original request is in the same format.

***code :***

```
GATE_API ='https://gateway-stage-core.milton.com/auth/oauth2/token'

payload = {'id': '8888yxy','secret':'vUz65MZ','type' : 'client','consumer_id' : '673d5881'}
print payload

r = requests.post(GATE_API, params = payload, verify=False)
print r.url
```

***output :***

```
{'secret': 'vUz65MZ', 'type': 'client', 'id': '8888yxy', 'consumer_id': '673d5881'}
https://gateway-stage-core.milton.com/auth/oauth2/token?client_secret=vUz65MZ&type=client&id=8888yxy&consumer_id=673d5881
```

But in the original code, I have to pass these credentials as a parameter. The output URL is coming with a lot of junk values and not able to match the above one..

***Code:***

```
GATE_API ='https://gateway-stage-core.milton.com/auth/oauth2/token'
ID = '8888yxy'
SECRET = 'vUz65MZ'
TYPE = 'client'
CONSUMER_ID= '673d5881'

payload = '{' + '"' + 'id' + '"' + ':' + '"' + ID + '"' + "," + '"' + 'secret' + '"' + ':' + '"' + SECRET + '"' + "," +'"' + 'type' + '"' + ':' + '"' + TYPE + '"' + "," + '"' + 'consumer_id' + '"' + ':' + '"' + CONSUMER_ID + '"' + '}`' 
print payload

r = requests.post(GATE_API, params = payload, verify=False)
print r.url
```

***Output :***

```
{"id":"8888yxy","secret":"vUz65MZ","type":"client","consumer_id":"673d5881"}
https://gateway-stage-core.milton.com/auth/oauth2/token?%7B%22id%22:%228888yxy%22,%22secret%22:%22vUz65MZ%22,%22type%22:%22client%22,%22consumer_id%22:%22673d5881%22%7D
```

Comment: It's not clear what your question is, exactly

Comment: In the 2nd example, I am trying to find out a way to remove those junk characters and achieve the URL as shown in the example 1.

Comment: It sounds like you've solved that already, though, by using the first code block and asking `requests` to generate the query-param string for you?

Comment: Yes, I am able to generate the format now.. I need to pass it in  the dictionary format , because of concatenation it was coming as string.. thanks for suggestions and help !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the second example you're passing the payload as a string, not a dict. The 'junk values' are escaped strings for the non-alphanumeric characters in the payload string.